# How to extract words out of a string with no spaces in python?

Tags: python, string, split, tweepy, textblob

I am still somewhat new to python so I am stuck on a problem that I don't know how to solve this particular problem in it.

So we have a string like "ThisThingIsCool" or "thisthingiscool"

Now I need to somehow make a list like [This,Thing,Is,Cool] or [this,thing,is,cool]

Currently, I am using textblob but I am not sure if they even have such a way to do such a thing.

I mean I downloaded the corpus (I am guessing that it's a list of words), but did not see any function to recognize a word in a garbled string and extract words. Leaving a list as an output.

So I want to settle with at least being able to split the one with a Capitalized letter. However I have no clue how to go about that in python.

So the question is

1. How do I recognize capitalized letters?
2. How do i split it without having the delimiter consumed?
3. Is there something in textblob that already does this?

Thank You

Comment: What you are asking is quite difficult to do easily, e.g. what do you do with `adultsexchange` - `[adults, exchange]` or `['adult', 'sex', 'change']`?

Comment: See  http://stackoverflow.com/a/41244596/4014959

Answer (score 3):

Splitting by capital letters is fairly easy with regular expressions:

```
s = "ThisThingIsCool"
re.findall(r'[A-Z][^A-Z]*', s)
#['This', 'Thing', 'Is', 'Cool']
```

The general solution is much harder and probably requires dynamic programming.

Comment: usage of `^` instead of explicitly specifying every regex makes the solution more generic!

Answer (score 0):

Use `re` module.

```
>>> a = 'ThisThingIsCool'
>>> import re
>>> re.findall(r'[A-Z][a-z]*', a)
['This', 'Thing', 'Is', 'Cool']
>>> [i.lower() for i in re.findall(r'[A-Z][a-z]*', a)]
['this', 'thing', 'is', 'cool']
>>> list(map(str.lower, re.findall(r'[A-Z][a-z]*', a)))
['this', 'thing', 'is', 'cool']
```

Comment: You solution ignores one-letter words and possible non-alphabethic characters.

Answer (score -1):

s = "This is my Name"
new_s = s.split()
print(new_s)

> > ['This', 'is', 'my', 'Name']

Comment: Usage of the `split()` function is perfect for delimited strings.
I would like to thumb it up but unfortunately the OP (Original Poster) asks about how to extract words that are "not" space delimited.