# Python3 - Make space after each word in mixed string

Tags: python, string

I've got a string:

> SzczęśliwyNumereknadzień06październikato:

and I want to make a space after each word. So the final result should look like this:

> Szczęśliwy Numerek na dzień 06 października to:

How can I reach that?

Here is my original string:

> ```
>     Szczęśliwy Numerek na dzień 
>     06 października 
>     to:
> ```

Later I removed whitespace, so my string was looking like that:

> ```
> SzczęśliwyNumereknadzień
> 06października
> to:
> ```

And after that, I converted it to one line string, and it's now looking like this:

> SzczęśliwyNumereknadzień06październikato:

Comment: You need to determine how you define a word boundary in python

Comment: There is nothing definite that splits the words. If they begin with CAPS or something that's a common pattern, a program can be made. This seems like manual work to me. Let's see if anyone else finds a solution.

Comment: How did you *get* the string with no spaces? Maybe you should start there

Comment: @cricket_007 Check my edit.

Comment: @xaos_xv so why don't you work with the string that's got spaces in it and just remove the line breaks from it?

Comment: Why did you get rid of all the spaces? It's _possible_ to split a sequence of letters into separate words, if you have a good dictionary file, but it's a bit tedious, and there are usually multiple solutions. So it's better to not lose those word boundaries in the first place!

Comment: I've never tried to do this sort of thing with Polish, but [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41244596/4014959) is an example of doing it with English, using a Scrabble dictionary. But as I said above, it's better if you can avoid doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
string="""                            Szczęśliwy Numerek na dzień 
                            06 października 
                            to:
"""
strings=' '.join(string.split())
```

Comment: Thanks. It helps me a lot !

Comment: Err... Why not just: `' '.join(string.split())` ?