# Find indexes (start and end) of longest common substrings, ignoring spaces

Tags: python

I have a problem as follow: I have two versions of the same dataset.
Version 1 has the correct texts but sometimes incorrect spacing.
Version 2 has the correct spacing but sometimes has missing/extra texts.

I want to merge these two into a dataset with both correct texts and spacing.

For example:

```
str_v1 = 'the fo xjumped overt he laz y dog'  
str_v2 = 'fox jumped over the lazy dog cat'  
# expected string: the fox jumped over the lazy dog
```

My idea is to somehow compare these two strings and find the indexes of the longest common substrings while ignoring spaces.
Then take the common portion from str_v2, adding the first and last portion from str_v1:

```
# I don't know how to do this part  
str_v1_common_start = 4 (the letter 'f' in fox)  
str_v1_common_end = 32 (the letter 'g' in dog)  
str_v2_common_start = 0 (the letter 'f' in fox)   
str_v2_common_end = 27 (the letter 'g' in dog)
```

The str_expected could be formed as:

```
str_expected = str_v1[:str_v1_common_start] + str_v2[str_v2_common_start: str_v2_common_end] + str_v1 [str_v1_common_end:]
```

I'm not sure this is the best idea yet. I'm very new to python so if anyone can help with the execution or suggest better idea i'd be very grateful. Thank you very much.

Comment: I would remove all the spaces in the first dataset, this use the link here to extract the words then construct the sentence.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41241216/fast-way-to-break-a-joined-string-of-words-into-individual-words/41244596#41244596

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately the real data is a bit technical and not fully English words (has numbers, symbols, punctuations, IDs, date,...) so dictionary probably would not work well.

Comment: What would happen in the case of `s1 = "thecow jumped overthemoon" s2 = "the cow"`

Comment: in that case it should return "the cow jumped overthemoon". ideally, the "over the moon" part (with correct spacing) should be located in the next cell of s2 and once i figured out how to compare-and-merge, i can do another iteration with the next cell

Comment: To clarify, the missing/extra texts in version 2 is because it was incorrectly append to previous/next cells (this is an error caused by incorrect column detection by libraries when parsing tables in PDF files). ideally for each comparison i can check 3 cells: current, previous and next to locate the common substring and extract the correct spacing, however i think i can do this on my own so the scope of the question does not mention this.

Comment: How do you expect to [reliably] convert 'overthemoon' to 'over the moon' bearing mind that, although nonsensical, 'overt he moon' are all valid words?

Comment: because "over the moon" (with correct spacing) exist in version2 and will be use as reference for spacing? Both version contains the same texts as a whole (if you strip all spaces and concat all cells together), they differ in what is in each cell. version1 has the correct texts in cell but bad spacing. version2 has the correct spacing but text might be wrongly allocated in the next/previous cells.

Comment: Please focus on the general question on finding positions of longest common subtring while ignoring space. Other previously answered questions on Stackoverflow only deal with extracting the substring (not the positions) and does not mention how to ignore spaces. Other techniques I think are specific to my case.

Answer (score 0):

To anyone who might encounter the same need, I have managed to do it with SequenceMatcher:

```
# Strip all spaces
str_v1_nospace = str_v1.replace(' ', '')
str_v2_nospace = str_v2.replace(' ', '')

# Find longest common substring
matcher = SequenceMatcher(None, str_v1_nospace, str_v2_nospace)
match = matcher.find_longest_match(0, len(str_v1_nospace), 0, len(str_v2_nospace))

# Start and end positions of common string in nospace strings
str_v1_common_start = match.a
str_v1_common_end = match.a + match.size - 1
str_v2_common_start = match.b 
str_v2_common_end = match.b + match.size - 1

# Function to find start and end positions in original string from positions in nospace strings
def find_character_position(input_string, index):
    count = -1
    position = -1
    for i, char in enumerate(input_string):
        if char != ' ':
            count += 1
            if count == index:
                position = i
                break
    return position

# Start and end positions of common string in original strings
str_v1_common_start = find_character_position(str_v1,str_v1_common_start)
str_v1_common_end = find_character_position(str_v1,str_v1_common_end)
str_v2_common_start = find_character_position(str_v2,str_v2_common_start)
str_v2_common_end = find_character_position(str_v2,str_v2_common_end)
```